# add blink to customized listview Item?

Tags: android, listview, border, android-animation

i have created a `listview` contains multiple items, and i added a border to those items so it would look like this:

[image]

because of this customized border the original blink of an item get blocked so it doesn't appear, and i've tried to add a blink through animation but there is too much delay and too much work on the main thread, i also used animation inside threads but it is the same with the delay thing, which force me to forget about animation so is there anyway that i can make the item blink when its clicked without using animation or with using it but in an efficient way and by the way i used blink animation inside my `onItemClickListener` you can find it in the code below:
`onItemClickListener` that handle the blink:

```
dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1,
                        final int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tvWarningNoEmp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // adding blink

                                final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(
                                        1, 0); // Change
                                // alpha
                                // from
                                // fully
                                // visible
                                // to
                                // invisible
                                animation.setDuration(100); // duration - half a
                                                            // second
                                animation
                                        .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do
                                // not
                                // alter
                                // animation
                                // rate
                                animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat
                                // animation
                                // infinitely
                                animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                                arg1.startAnimation(animation);
                                // blink one time timer
                                new CountDownTimer(100, 100) {// CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText())
                                                                // also parse it to long

                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                        // here you can have your logic to set text to
                                        // edittext
                                    }

                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        arg1.clearAnimation();
                                    }
                                }.start();



                                // set margins for tickets buttons
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                params.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 0);
                                bAssign.setLayoutParams(params);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                paramsO.setMargins(110, 0, 0, 0);
                                bEmpChat.setLayoutParams(paramsO);
                                noEmpLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                                empLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                                Employee item = adapter.getItem(arg2);
                                ivEmpIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.free);
                                tvEmpName.setText(" " + item.getEmpName());
                                tvEmpDetails.setText(" " + item.getEmpDetails());
                                empLongitude = item.getEmpLongitude();
                                empLatitude = item.getEmpLatitude();
                                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                        .target(new LatLng(empLatitude, empLongitude))
                                        .zoom(15).build();
                                googleEmpMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                                        new LatLng(empLatitude, empLongitude)).title(
                                        tvEmpName.getText().toString());
                                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                googleEmpMap.addMarker(marker);
                                // based on item add info to intent
                                // hide button directions
                                bEmpDirections.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                // current address
                                Geocoder geocoder;
                                List<Address> addresses;
                                geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale
                                        .getDefault());
                                try {
                                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(empLatitude,
                                            empLongitude, 1);
                                    String street = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                    tvEmpCurrentAdd.setText(" " + country + "-" + state
                                            + "-" + street + " st.");
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();}





                }

            });
```

ListView Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/redborder" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWarningNoEmp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="choose an employee from here to assign this problem to!"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/pepsiborder"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/TicketIcon"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketCat"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/ticketMap"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="State:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketState"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ticket No:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketNo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Report Date:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketReportDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView13"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Details:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ticketDetails"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnTicketDirections"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/directions" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSolve"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/solve" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnOther"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/other" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/llListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/pepsiborder"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView124"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#D3D9FF"
        android:text="Free Employees"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listTic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" >

    </ListView>
  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/noempLayout"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView 
         android:text="Please select free Employee to handle this problem!"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/empLayout"
                android:background="@drawable/pepsiborder"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/empIcon"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/empName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/empMap"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView33"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Current Address:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/empAddress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />
                    </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView22"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Details:"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/empDetails"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#D3D9FF" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llBtn2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnEmpDirections"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/directions" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnEmpChat"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/chat" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnEmpAssign"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/assign" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 

         />
    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#D3D9FF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
           />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#D3D9FF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
           />
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle"
       >
   <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#8D8D8D" />
   <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
   <solid android:color="#464A4F" />
</shape>
```

any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Holy nested layouts! Way too many nested LinearLayouts in your list file. Are you simply trying to make the list item visually respond to touch by changing the background color?

Comment: it does much much more than that but yeah eventually i want the item to blink when its clicked and i'm having a difficult time dealing with the delay that occurs because of the inefficiency of my code, the activity do too much work on the layout like hiding some and showing others and set margins all dynamically so i'm thinking about making 2 activities to handle 2 different layouts instead of hiding most of them dynamically  or i may use fragments DK any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i figure out how to reduce the delay and add blink effect without using animation and some how it worked for me and there is no more delay, what i did is I've changed the list's linear layouts to relative and that reduced the amount of nested layouts significantly  then i added this method:

```
private void blink(final View v){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in milissegunds
        try{Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch (Exception e) {}
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {

                    if(v == View.VISIBLE){
                        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    blink();
                }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

then i used it inside `onItemClickListener()` --> `blink(arg1);`
worked perfectly for me, also getting the current address was taking too much so i used Async so now there is no delay at all:
Async used as an inner class:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String all;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // current address
            Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;

            geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale
                    .getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(empLatitude,
                        empLongitude, 1);
                String street = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                all="" + country + "-" + state
                        + "-" + street + " st.";

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();}
            return all;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tvEmpCurrentAdd.setText(all);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

and then i called it inside `onItemClickListener`:
`new LongOperation().execute()`;
hope this will help others that had simillar problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view to blink:

```
public void blink(final View v) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        v.animate().setDuration(25).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.standard_key_normal);
                v.setAlpha(1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Send your View to this function, replace the background with whatever drawable or color resource you want. If you want multiple blinks put it in a for loop.

Comment: sir i'm trying to avoid animations, when i use it inside my onItemClickListener the blink happens after the other layouts and functionality are loaded for example the onClickListener() method make other layouts visible, set margins,  load address, get employee data from the adapter and many other things, you can check out the method above.